# Parse Pilcrows From String

Tags: .net, string, parsing

This is frustrating me.  I have a String that has two pilcrows in it.  It looks like I can't put pilcrows in here so here is an image of it:
[image]

How can I parse out the pilcrows from the String named, NameOfUser?  I have tried:

```
NameOfUser.IndexOf(Chr(182))
```

But that doesn't work, returns a -1.  I have also tried copying and pasting the pilcrow to pass that as the parameter, but it wouldn't allow that character in Visual Studio.  So I'm at a loss here, if anyone could help me out.  I feel it has to be a simple syntax thing that I'm missing.

thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ALT + 0182` right within the string value in Visual Studio code editor. See if this makes a difference. Also check the integer Unicode value of the character at the particular index.

Comment: if you have the index of that character, it would simply by `(int)(NameOfUser[76])`, where 76 is your index. I'm using C# syntax.

Comment: Figured it out, it was Char 20.  I used AscW to return the Unicode value of the character. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy-paste the pilcrow. This works for me:

```
 NameOfUser.IndexOf("¶"c)
```

Or use the [`ChrW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function:

```
NameOfUser.IndexOf(ChrW(182))
```

Comment: unfortunately copying and pasting the pilcrow doesn't work for me and I figured out the Unicode value was actually 20. Weird.

Comment: @Justin That's not a true pilcrow, it's a [control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes). Perhaps the Pilcrow is just a placeholder for the control character used by whatever editor you're using.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense.  That's why I wasn't able to find it when I was passing it Chr(182).

Comment: @Justin Over the years, I've learned that if a basic string function isn't working the way you think it should, never trust your eyes. Dissect the string into individual chars and see what it *really* is.